# Why does ctypes WriteProcessMemory() fail?

Tags: python, ctypes

I have been trying to get this function working for some time now with no luck.

```
def write_memory(self, address, data):
    PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS = 0x001F0FFF
    count = c_ulong(0)
    length = len(data)
    c_data = c_char_p(data[count.value:])
    null = c_int(0)
    windll.kernel32.SetLastError(10000)
    if not windll.kernel32.WriteProcessMemory(self.h_process, address, c_data, length, byref(count)):
        print "Failed to write memory."
        print  "Error Code: ", windll.kernel32.GetLastError()
    else:
        return True
```

GetLastError() returns 87 (0x57), which is ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER.
For this function I copied it straight from Gray Hat Python by Justin Seitz.
Not sure what I'm doing wrong, ReadProcessMemory() works great and returns the appropriate value.

For address I'm picking a random location at the moment, 0x00050000, and passing data like "\x61" reading the location before and after with no change.

I have the feeling It's a simple error, Thanks in advance for the help. Nav.

---

While you were right It's a privilege thing. I still can't seem to figure out what I'm looking for. Here's my launch process code:

```
class SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES(Structure):
    _fields_ = [("Length", DWORD),
                ("SecDescriptor", LPVOID),
                ("InheritHandle", BOOL)]

def launch(self, path_to_exe):
    CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE = 0x0000010

    startupinfo = STARTUPINFO()
    process_information = PROCESS_INFORMATION()
    security_attributes = SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES()

    startupinfo.dwFlags = 0x1
    startupinfo.wShowWindow = 0x0


    startupinfo.cb = sizeof(startupinfo)
    security_attributes.Length = sizeof(security_attributes)
    security_attributes.SecDescriptior = None
    security_attributes.InheritHandle = True



    if windll.kernel32.CreateProcessA(path_to_exe,
                               None,
                               byref(security_attributes),
                               byref(security_attributes),
                               True,
                               CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE,
                               None,
                               None,
                               byref(startupinfo),
                               byref(process_information)):

        self.pid = process_information.dwProcessId
    else:
        print "Couldnt launch: %d" %path_to_exe
        print windll.kernel32.GetLastError()
```

Do I need to create the process a different way? What should I be putting in the SecDescriptor struct? MSDN isn't very helpful going on about DACL's and ACE's?
Thanks for all the help so far.

PS - Just an idea, how does a debugger or some other program not spawn a process and is able to alter memory?

Comment: I deleted my answer about the temporary string possibly being freed up before you call the win32 routine, since a check with sys.getrefcount() shows that c_char_p() does preserve an internal reference to the data.

Comment: Thank you, I appreciate the help in the first place, any other ideas?

Comment: Usually a debugger DOES spawn the processes it debugs.  It's ability to debug processes that it doesn't spawn is limited.  I think the just-in-time debugging facility gives the debugger some rights it wouldn't normally have (at the discretion of the user).

Comment: try adding `CREATE_PRESERVE_CODE_AUTHZ_LEVEL` to `CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE`.  It's also possible that CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE is the problem here, can you do without it?

Comment: what version of windows? some of this stuff changed with WinXP SP2.

Comment: Sadly, I've tried that too. I'm really stumped with this. BTW using vistaSP2 32 bit. I placed this while file up on google code if anyone would like a look. -- http://code.google.com/p/botbasics/
I'm running out of ideas.

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing obviously wrong with the call.  Most likely there just aren't any pages at 0x00050000 or the pages there aren't writable.

Why don't you try doing a `VirtualQuery` on the bytes you are trying to write to and see if it's actually writable? Most random addresses aren't.

Comment: I just added a function for VirtualQuery and it returned 0, which means it failed. GetLastError() is returning 998 which is ERROR_NOACCESS or Invalid access to memory location.

Comment: Is there something I need to do to be able to write to the locations? I thought that opening the process handle with PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS was enough. Am I wrong?

Comment: You can't write where there is no memory.  But if you are getting ERROR_NOACCESS, that probably means that this is a privilege thing.  Opening the process with PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS doesn't do you any good if the process itself doesn't allow outside processes to write to it.  If this were a CHILD process (one that you created), then you could give yourself write access to it when you created it.